# Dragging files onto Sublime (or any custom program) in Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, sublime-text

A while ago, I followed tutorial which told me how to "install" sublime so that it behaved like a standard program, with a unity icon I could lock on the launcher. I also set Sublime so that it was the default application to open text files.

There is still one thing that it does not do. If I drag a file from nautilus onto the launcher, all the apps fade away, but the ones which can open it do not (Gedit does not fade away). I can then drop the file onto an application which can handle it and that application with open it.

This does not happen for Sublime, how do I configure this to happen?

Comment: How did you get it into the launcher?  Did you write a `.desktop` file?

Comment: I can't find the tutorial I used, but I am pretty sure that was how I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the MIME types of the files you want to open to the `.desktop` file.

Propably the mostr easy way to do this is to use [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/):

1. Open Arronax
2. Drag the Sublime symbol from the Dash into the Arronax window. This loads the `.desktop` file.
3. Open the "MIME types" tab in Arronax
4. Drag some files of the type you want to open from nautilus into the MIME types input field. You will see the MIME types added.
5. Save the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/`. The "User App folder" button in the "Save" dialog will take you to that folder.

[image: Arronax with MIME taype tab open]